# Is this csrf failure expected?

Tags: python, django, django-csrf

Given the following series of events

1. anonymous user opens home page, which contains a form (with a valid csrf token)
2. the user opens a secondary tab and logs in.
3. the user returns to the original tab and submits the form.

Is the resulting csrf failure expected, and if so, are there any solutions that will give the user a better experience?

Comment: Briefly, that is to be expected (since the token changes when you log in), and I can't think of a straightforward way of avoiding the csrf failure. Hopefully someone will give you a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is part of the security system.  Given that the CSRF token belonged to the anonymous user could potentially be generated/acquired by the attacker (as they are anonymous users also), it is definitely not a wise idea to use that token after the user has logged in.  Django [documents this behavior](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/#why-might-a-user-encounter-a-csrf-validation-failure-after-logging-in) as a security measure, and they have a [relevant ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24786) documenting [why they do this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22903/why-refresh-csrf-token-per-form-request/22936#22936).

This is also why some sites (such as github) will warn the user that they need to reload the page on all other tabs of the users' browser session if a login/logout was done in one tab.  There is no safe measure to avoid this.

Comment: I think that you can automatically refresh page (or just some parts), if you detect that authentication cookies have changed. I assume this is how google deals with this situation.

Comment: Thanks for the doc reference. I'm not sure I understand your first two sentences though..  A csrf token is generated on step 1 (let's call it csrf-1). When the (same) user opens the secondary tab, csrf-1 is sent - and returned unchanged. When the user logs in (in the secondary tab), the csrf-1 token is sent from browser to server, and a new csrf token (csrf-2) is returned from the server and set in the browser.  csrf-2 doesn't match the input=hidden csrf-1 token in the form on the original tab.

Comment: @thebjorn csrf-1 is generated as the original anonymous user, so it can in theory the same token can be generated by another hostile anonymous user. If the hostile user can trick the original anonymous user to visit their page, and convince them to log into the django site, if the original csrf token is still valid, the attacker can then trigger the post action to submit their version of the data on behalf of the original user, thus triggering the csrf attack (however contrive this is, this attack vector is real).

Comment: @metatoaster I'm not sure how a hostile anonymous user can generate the same token. It sounds like you're saying that csrf-1 is shared among all anonymous users, but that is not the case. In a GET request (where the response contains a form), one of two things can happen: if the browser has never been to the site before, no `Cookie:` header will be sent from browser to server, and the server will generate a fresh/unique csrf token and return it through a `Set-Cookie:` header. If it's a known site, the server will simply echo the csrf token that the browser sends.

Comment: As I said this is in theory that it is possible, if there are vulnerabilities with the anonymous CSRF token generation this can be compromised,  This is why it is always good to **never** mix/recycle tokens when a context is changed to fully and surely eliminate this class of attack.

Comment: @metatoaster I'm still not seeing how this is different from guessing a csrf token of a logged in user..? If we assume that it's true, do you have any solution for the second part of my question? As it is, the end user is experiencing the site as flaky since for them they randomly have to refresh the page before they can submit a form.

Comment: Be glad they don't [refresh the CSRF token validation per request](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22903/why-refresh-csrf-token-per-form-request) (as that doesn't really improve security), but instead they do so to prevent [session fixation attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation#Attacks_using_cross-subdomain_cookie).  This is essentially what I mean when it is possible to generate the same csrf token because if the attacker has control over what/when the user visit your site, they can control the contents of the csrf token when the user is anonymous.

Comment: Also, if you still don't believe me, that thread also what [django developers cite](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24786) as to why they do this, and they will not fix this.

Comment: Django developers have been wrong many times ;-)  I'm interpreting you to say that you know of no solution to the user experience issue, correct?

Comment: Sure, naturally that may be the case, but for this particular one they are correct as it stops _all_ possible session fixation cases even in edge cases that allow the first cookie to be more easily fixed by the attacker. Security for webapps **only** just barely works by applying all applicable countermeasures that compliment each other. As for a solution, I did note that reloading the page is the only way, which your application can do automatically for your users (or at least just reload the token bit as @AndrewMorozko suggested.

Answer (score 0):

For this exact issue, and provided Django's `CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY` has its default value of False, this onfocus handler seems to work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).on('focus', function () {

         var cookie_csrf = dk.web.cookie.get('csrftoken');  // or Cookie.get(..) or something similar
         var dom_csrf = $('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]:first');

         if (cookie_csrf !== dom_csrf) {
             // other tab has caused the csrf cookie to change
             $('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').each(function () {
                 $(this).val(cookie_csrf);
             });
         }
    });
});
```

it seems a bit hackish, so perhaps refreshing the page is "better":

```
if (cookie_csrf !== dom_csrf) {
    window.location.reload(true);  // reload the current page, without using the cache
}
```

refreshing the page will get any changes to the page that results from logging in, but delete any input the user has entered.

It's safe to access the csrf token from .js assuming you have no XSS vulnerabilities (which is generally assumed when it comes to csrf).

This technique relies on the fact that the value of the csrf token in the cookie and in the dom are identical, which they are in Django by design.